# group join with left join group return null

Tags: c#, linq

I have a group join with 2 joins group, one of the group joins can be null, in my query C is the group that I join with a left join this query give me and null exception

```
from A in contexto.A.Where(i => i.EmpresaId == id)                             
                            join B in contexto.B
                                on A.Id equals B.AId
                            join D in contexto.D
                                on B.BId equals D.Id
                           join C in contexto.C
                                on A.Id equals C.AId
                           into c
                           from C in c.DefaultIfEmpty()

                           group new { A, C, D} by A into grupo
                           select new ADTO{
                               Clave = grupo.Key.Clave,
                               Nombre = grupo.Key.Nombre,
                               Lista1 = grupo.Select(t =>                                    
                                 t.D.Nombre                                     
                               ).ToList(),
                               Valores1 = grupo.Select(t => new ValorDTO
                               {
                                   a= t.C.A,
                                   b= t.C.B,
                                   c= t.C.c
                               }
                               ).DefaultIfEmpty(new ValorBMDTO()).ToList()
                           }).ToList();
```

Comment: you can try replacing `.` with `?.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators at the part(s) that might be `null`. I don't think you can get any answer without more detail on exactly where the exception is.

Comment: @Slai you can't use `?.` (null conditional operators) with LINQ to SQL / EF as it isn't yet supported :(